# Apache fails to start

Tags: apache2

I recently updated my ubuntu server from 12.04 to 14.04. Now apache won't work correctly. This is the error I get when restarting apache2.

```
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                                                                      [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 210 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Line 210 in apache2.conf is:

```
Include mods-enabled/*.load
```

I cant seem to find any issues related to this.

Comment: Please check the apache error log. Any of one module is not loading in apache.
Please use the command to check error log. <pre> tailf /var/log/apache2/error.log </pre>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 210 on `apache2.conf` loads all the modules on `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/` which are symlinks to `/etc/apache2/mods-available/`, run this command to see if the symlink is broken

```
ls -la /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

If so, delete the symlink and try to restart apache again

```
sudo unlink /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_default.load
sudo service apache restart
```

It's possible that you need to disable other modules too, or reinstall them if necessary.

Note: The usual way of disabling mods (which remove symlinks internally) is using `a2dismod`, but i dont know if it works on broken mods/synlinks.